# MapKit Map() custom user location annotation

Tags: dictionary, swiftui, mapkit

I've got a Map() in my code, don't think you need my code as it's literally just a Map() with the region set. But I was wondering how I can customize the `showsUserLocation: True` . I want it to display an SF Symbol icon.

Let me know if you need anything else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach to display a `SF Symbol` at a desired location, works well for me.

```
 import Foundation
 import SwiftUI
 import MapKit
 import CoreLocation

 struct ContentView: View {
     var body: some View {
         MapView()
     }
 }

 struct MyLocation: Identifiable {
     let id = UUID()
     var name: String
     var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
 }

 struct MapView: View {
     
     @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.661991, longitude: 139.762735), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0925, longitudeDelta: 0.0925))
     
     // simulated user location
     @State var myLocations = [MyLocation(name: "tokyo", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.661991, longitude: 139.762735))]

     var body: some View {
         Map(coordinateRegion: $region, interactionModes: .all,
             showsUserLocation: true,
             userTrackingMode: .constant(.follow),
             annotationItems: myLocations) { myLoc in
             
             MapAnnotation(coordinate: myLoc.coordinate) {
                 Image(systemName: "figure.wave").resizable()  // <-- here
                     .frame(width: 33, height: 33)
                     .foregroundColor(.red)
             }
         }
     }
 }
```